# PHP DISTINCT not work in two rows

Tags: php, mysql

I work with this MySQL Table for user news poster:

```
| id |   name    | newsid  |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1  |   eric    |   20    |
| 2  |   eric    |   25    |
| 3  |   dave    |   89    |
| 4  |   dave    |   93    |
| 5  |   maria   |   77    |
```

I print list of user with `DISTINCT` methos like this :

```
   $fileName = Access::fetch("SELECT  DISTINCT (name) AS name ,id FROM news_poster");
   foreach($fileName as $key => $value){
   $row_array['id'] = $value['id'];
   $row_array['name'] = $value['name'];
   $rows2[]=$row_array;
   }

   echo json_encode($rows2);
```

in output I see:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"eric"},{"id":"2","name":"eric"},{"id":"3","name":"dave"},{"id":"4","name":"dave"},{"id":"5","name":"maria"}]
```

I need to print This :

```
[{"id":"1","name":"eric"},{"id":"3","name":"dave"},{"id":"5","name":"maria"}]
```

how do print this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT` applies to the ENTIRE row. it's not a function call, though you CAN use `()` for it.

`1/eric` and `2/eric` are distinct records as far as a `select distinct` is concerned, because the values are different.

If you want a SINGLE eric record, then you do something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

They are indeed distinct records.

You want to use `GROUP BY` name in this case